# What's a good "visual design pattern" for links that contain icons?

Tags: html, css, design-patterns, styling

I would like to create links that have icons included in the link.

For example, take a modified version of the chat/meta/faq links from Stack Overflow.

[Here is one attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/ripper234/q2vE4/3/).

**HTML**

```
<div id='clickable'>
  <a href="#chat">
    <div class='so-icon'></div>
    chat
  </a>
  ...
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#clickable div {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.so-icon {
  background-image:url(http://www.madhur.co.in/images/icon_stackoverflow3.png);
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;    
  margin-right: 10px;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

The one problem with this design is that the underline (hover over the link to see) appears on more than just the link text, but also on some whitespace before that.

[image]

A couple of solutions I can think of are:

- Having two separate `<a>` elements, one for the icon, and one for the text. Violates [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).
- Not using a elements at all, but rather javascript, to implement the link functionality, while styling both the icon and text/span elements separately.

Isn't this something that should be possible to accomplish using CSS only, and not having to recourse to javascript?

Comment: I'm using display:block; for the a elements in my projects which works for me very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this??

http://jsfiddle.net/HBawG/

```
a p:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

I tried to edit your work

Hope i helped.

Comment: For the record, I actually prefer `span` instead of `p` for this, but it's the same principle.

Answer (score 2):

Here we go, a solution with no additional markup or pseudo-elements, based on @sandeep's.

http://jsfiddle.net/z4Gs2/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the background image directly to the  tag.  Something like this:

```
<a href="#chat" class="so-icon">chat</a>
<a href="#meta" class="so-icon">meta</a>
<a href="#faq" class="so-icon">faq</a>
```

with the CSS:

```
.so-icon {
  background:url(http://www.madhur.co.in/images/icon_stackoverflow3.png) no-repeat left center;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin:10px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: @ripper234 - As with mine, because the HTML doesn't contain a spurious `<div>` element just to hold the image.

Comment: @Chowlett - I kind of prefer having a div element dedicated to holding the icon. I guess it's a matter of taste ... at least the accepted answer doesn't have magic constants such as `padding-left: 35px`;

Comment: The `padding-left: 35px` is just giving room for the 30px-wide icon + 5px of padding between the icon and text.  It would have been better for me to combine the a and .so-icon into a single ruleset, so that the relationship is more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the carriage return between your div (image) and your hyperlink text (to avoid undesired blank spaces)
Then you should modify the css of .so-icon class adding `margin-right: 5px` (for example)

You can find the modified version of your example here
http://jsfiddle.net/q2vE4/4/

Comment: I prefer @Bert's answer. I don't want my HTML source to be all one-liner.